# Laravel Eloquent orWhere issues

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Been wandering what's wrong with my query should be as easy as it seems.
its more like i'm creating a    select * from table where (a = 1 and b =2)
or (a = 2 and b = 1) type of query.  Here's my eloquent.

```
return $query->where(function($q) use ($brand, $influencer, $agency){
    $q->where([
        'sender_id' => $brand,
        'receiver_id' => $influencer
    ]);
    $q->orWhere([
        'sender_id' => $influencer,
        'receiver_id' => $brand
    ]);
});
```

I have this query in my eloquent but when display in debug bar it's showing

```
select count(*) as aggregate
from `chat_messages`
where ((`sender_id` = '415' and `receiver_id` = '1159')
or (`sender_id` = '1159' or `receiver_id` = '415'))
```

and i wanted it to be "AND" inside the second parenthesis group

```
select count(*) as aggregate
from `chat_messages`
where ((`sender_id` = '415' and `receiver_id` = '1159')
or (`sender_id` = '1159' AND `receiver_id` = '415'))
```

Comment: its running on Laravel  5.5.40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `orWhere()` with an array, it uses `OR` in front and between the individual constraints.

Use this:

```php
return $query->where(function($q) use ($brand, $influencer, $agency){
    $q->where([
        'sender_id' => $brand,
        'receiver_id' => $influencer
    ])->orWhere(function($q) use ($brand, $influencer) {
        $q->where([
            'sender_id' => $influencer,
            'receiver_id' => $brand
        ]);                
    });
});
```

Comment: @Kruze if it is working then accept it as answer, for future user